# Getting an array result back from index-match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So a bit different from most index-match array questions

I have a table of movements from A to B. I can have movement Type 1, Type 2, Type 3, or Type 4.

Each of these movements corresponds to a different set of "Roll up steps". These would be Step 1, Step 2, or Step 3.

This relationship is captured in a neat table, like so:

```
Step      Type   Relationship
Step 1 - Type 1 - 1
Step 2 - Type 1 - 0
Step 3 - Type 1 - 0
Step 1 - Type 2 - 1
Step 2 - Type 2 - 1
Step 3 - Type 2 - 0
Step 1 - Type 3 - 0
Step 2 - Type 3 - 0
Step 3 - Type 3 - 1
Step 1 - Type 4 - 1
Step 2 - Type 4 - 1
Step 3 - Type 4 - 1
```

Where a 1 is "Yes they're related" and a 0 is "No they're not".

Now there's a substep to step table, looks like so:

```
SubStep  --- Step
1             1
2             1
3             1
4             1
5             1
6             1
7             2
8             2
9             2
10            3
11            3
12            3
```

Now, I have a table of substeps, and how many substeps I need to take. I have a table of movements, and how many units of movements are being moved from A to B. I'm trying to work out how many units need to be added to each substep.

For example:

If I have movement type 1 for 100 units, I'd need to add 100 units to substep 1 - 6. If I then have movement type 2 for 200 units, I'd need to add an additional 200 units to substep 1-6, for a total of 300 units moved, and then 200 units added to substeps 7-9.

I've worked out that a sumproduct is probably the best way to do this. Currently the first part of it looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Units],--(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Month]=[@Month]),--(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Year]=[@Year]),--(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[From]=[@[Lab Abbr]]),--(INDEX(MovementToStepLookup[Roll up Step],MATCH(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Movement Type],MovementToStepLookup[Movement Number],0))=[@[Roll up Step]]))
```

However, the part that's not working is the `(INDEX(MovementToStepLookup[Roll up Step],MATCH(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Movement Type],MovementToStepLookup[Movement Number],0))=[@[Roll up Step]]))` - I'd expect to get a TRUE/FALSE array out of it, but instead I just get a #VALUE error. The Index properly gives me the array, the Match properly generates an array, when merging the two (when stepping through) it only gives me one number as a result, instead of an array of numbers, then it's giving me (For example) {1} = 1, then a single TRUE.

This works when I'm stepping through the formula, but when I highlight the entire thing to calculate, it just gives me #VALUE. So I suppose I have two questions (Really, the only question is how to get my data pulled through, but breaking it down a bit....):

1) How do I get my index-match to return an array result?
2) What am I doing wrong in my formula?

Answer (score 0):

So after a LOT more googling, the answer is strange and counter intuitive, and as of writing, I don't actually know all of the reasons WHY it works, just that it (seems to be!) working.

I had a mistake earlier where I was pulling out the rollup step, then comparing that. That was incorrect, I needed to be pulling out if it was used or not. The match has changed slightly to reflect this.

The way to coerce Index to returning multiple results appears to be twofold: 1) To have a conditional statement, 2) To have the N function, like so:

INDEX(MovementToStepLookup[Used?],N(IF(TRUE,MATCH(UnitMovementWorksheetCurrent[Movement Type],MovementToStepLookup[Movement Number]*(MovementToStepLookup[Roll up Step]=[@[Roll up Step]]),0))))

For my conditional, I just had it as TRUE. Why bother with anything more complex? For the N, simply pass it the array.

I have NO IDEA why this works. The (much better article) explaining how to do it says they're not sure why either. More reading can be found here: https://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/ . However, it does work, so I'm happy